# Query returning {} when it should return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im having trouble with a mongdb query returning {} from my node.js code.

Here is how I am building my query string in node.js javascript:

```
var idString = '' + firstId; // firstId = 1
var otheridString = '' + secondId; // secondId = 2

var users = { userid: { $in : [idString, otheridString] }};
```

But when I run this through nodeJS/mongo it returns {}

If I run this directly in the DB it returns the two rows

```
db.Users.find({ userid: { $in : ["1", "2"] }})
```

I think this has something to do with the userid's being strings, as if i run this query directly in the DB it returns {} also

```
db.Users.find({ userid: { $in : [1, 2] }})
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Presumably you’re storing your ID as a string then as opposed to a number?

Comment: yes its a string

Comment: Should work then, `’’ + num` should convert `num` to a string based on coercion - sure it’s not a data issue? Are the ids what you expect after the conversion?

Comment: yes when i console.dir(users) i get this which looks right.  { userid: { '$in': [ '1', '2' ] } }

Comment: actually i just noticed the quotes around $in... that might be the issue. Why would it be putting quotes around the $in character?  And how do i get it to not do that?

Comment: have you tried doing the query directly instead of setting it to the variable users and then using users in the query ? perhaps the query isn't what you expect it to be because the type of the data isn't what you're expecting either

Comment: @rakan316 it doesn't work either. So, it must have something to do with the quotes around the $in clause.  What would be causing this. Also any idea how i could rewrite that variable assignment to stop that from happening?

Comment: Ah I found the issue, it was a typo on in the mongo insert statement where i used the wrong variable name. Sorry for those who spent time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var idString = firstId.toString(); // firstId = 1
var otheridString = secondId.toString(); // secondId = 2

var users = { userid: { $in : [idString, otheridString] }};
```

Comment: I think userId is stored as objectId , if then , what about wrapping like this new ObjectId(userId) ?

Comment: `'' + num` is technically safer, `toString` would throw if `num` was `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @ganka - makes not difference.

Comment: @AhammadaliPK no its not an ObjectId. That would be "_id".

Comment: @James yes agreed.

Comment: @croc-hunter : I mean the type of that variable(_id)